# Why icon is appearing after few seconds on modal load

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, font-awesome

I have a web page that consists of huge number of data to be processed. What I am trying to do is to show a modal containing the advertisement on every page load.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Before You Begin.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
})
</script>
```

In this modal title I have one icon along with title. The modal is getting popup correctly. But my question is when this modal opens the icon is appearing few seconds after the modal opens.

Comment: Which icon you are talking about ? Exclamation triangle icon ?

Comment: Sanim is talking about font awesome icon i.e. `<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true">`

Comment: My icon is <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true">@HariDas

Comment: Probably the huge data is causing the client-side to work slowly, how do  you load it? Is it via ajax request? When do you load the data compared to the modal show?

Comment: Does this problem occur when the code shown is run in isolation (i.e., without the large quantity of data that is being processed)? Also, does it happen when you refresh the page? (Your code runs on DOM ready, which could be before the icon has downloaded...)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you will have added the cdn for the icons:

CDN https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Download the css (best way) or add the link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Works fine in my codepen: https://codepen.io/ricopo/pen/vmXwbK

Comment: I tried replacing bootstrap icon but the result is same.

Comment: The code in the question already has a document ready handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn I think you are right in your answer above. Can be by adding the css using url instead of downloading it?

Comment: for now, i just used an icon by <img src..... instead of that <i class.... which is working

Comment: And with the icon you have the css downloaded or you are using the url? I suppose the image is not an url but the relative path to image right? Have you try this @sanin? What happends if you put an url image?

Comment: its relative path. and it is working. anyways thankx